# How to retain jquery populated elements and values after form is submitted?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

There is a dropdown in my form which contains 2 options. Username and city. If somebody selects Username 2 username options will be dynamically added by Jquery. Similarly if City is selected 2 city options will be added.

This works fine, but dynamically added dropdowns and the selected value disappear once the form is submitted through PHP to the server. I need to retain last selected state even after the form is submitted. How do I accomplish this?

For example - Let's say somebody selects "City" and then he selects Colombo as the city option. After the form is submitted, I want the form to retain "City" & "Colombo" selected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Basic</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="post_jquery_element.php">
        <select name="choice" id="choice">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="username">Username</option>
            <option value="city">City</option>

        </select>
        <span id="update"></span>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>


    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script> 
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#choice").change(function(){
                var value=$("#choice").val();
                if(value==="username"){
                    var output="<select name='username' id='username'>";
                    output+="<option>Mike</option>";
                    output+="<option>John</option>";
                    output+="</select>";
                    $("#update").html(output);
                }else if (value==="city") {
                    var output="<select name='city' id='city'>";
                    output+="<option>NY</option>";
                    output+="<option>Colombo</option>";
                    output+="</select>";
                    $("#update").html(output);
                }

            });



        });



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could submit the FORM using ajax instead or you could use any persistent data client side as cookie/local or session storage and set some logic to delete persistent data when no more needed. Now it really depends your use case. You could even make server side script returning specific data depending what was passed as param to it. And maybe i'm missing some other ways. Indeed i think this question is too broad

Comment: or use sessions like when you submit the form to php ,then in php do it like this `$_SESSION=$_POST` this will store all the post values in session. and you have to write your form like this `<option value="colombo" <?$_SESSION['city']=="colombo"?selected:''>>`

Comment: @A.Wolff - I retrieve data from a db table which matches those selected parameters and display them. I will give it a try using ajax

Comment: @ user790454 - Can we use sessions with jquery. I mean options are listed in <script>